# Central widget position of layout

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmainwindow

Is there a way to postion or resize layout in central widget of qmain window.

I am trying to write an app with QMainWindow. I am setting different Layout in central widget but the spacing of those widgets are completely different

```
class MainApp(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
    
        self.statusBar().showMessage('Select any option to proceed',3000)
    
        self.setWindowTitle("CH APTMO App")
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1050,600)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
    
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


class InsideWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.From = QLabel("From")
        self.To = QLabel("To")
        self.Type = QLabel("Type")
        self.Number = QLabel("Number")
      
        from_list = ["val1","val2","val3"]
        self.fromentry = QComboBox()
        self.fromentry.setEditable(True)
        self.fromentry.addItems(from_list)
        self.toentry = QLineEdit()
        self.typeentry = QLineEdit()
        self.numentry = QLineEdit()
       
        self.receivebaglayout = QGridLayout()
       
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.From,0,0)
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.To,0,1)
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.Type,0,2)
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.Number,0,3)
    
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.fromentry,1,0)
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.toentry,1,1)
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.typeentry,1,2)
        self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.numentry,1,3)
    
        self.receivebaglayout.setSpacing(10)
    
        self.setLayout(self.receivebaglayout)
```

The layout is messed up the grid layout in the central widget is like this

Picture showing the spacing between row 1 and 2:
[image: picture showing the spacing between row 1 and 2]

If we add many widgets to the grid layout its been adjusted properly. But when having less widgets it is spreading all over the centralwidget layout.

How could we stop this?

Output expected is added

The output expected:
[image: The output expected]

Comment: Your question is unclear, 1) You have shown in your code 2 classes that are not related so it is recommended that you provide a [mre], 2) The result you want is not clear, could you put an image that illustrates what you want obtain?

Comment: The code is too big. Let me explain.
I have a Main Window class inside which i j=have a stacked centralwidget.
When setting the central widget with grid layout the spacing of buttons and text are spreaed all over the central widget.
Is there a way to specifically resize central widgets based on the layout buttons we use. or the layout should adjust that and set the central widget?

Comment: precisely, if the code of your project is too big then you must work so that it becomes an MRE. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]

Comment: @eyllanesc in the above picture you can see the input feilds are at bottom and text are on top. But i want them to be placed as TOP positionsed in central widget.

Comment: Your description is unclear, so in addition to the MRE an image is required that illustrates what you want to obtain (use paint or any similar tool and create an outline of what you want to obtain)

Comment: Sure let me work around and will paste it

Comment: try with `self.receivebaglayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)`

Comment: That worked. I still wonder how that  works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you indicate contradicts the image you added, with the code of the previous comment all items are placed in the upper position but in the image you provide it is placed in the middle part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Qt uses the sizePolicy to calculate the size of each row of the QGridLayout. In this case, the QLabel tends to stretch vertically and the QLineEdit and QComboBox do not see this behavior.

Since it is not clear what the OP wants I will offer several solutions depending on the case:

- If you want the items to be positioned towards the top then just add a stretch at the end of the row:

  ```
  self.receivebaglayout.setRowStretch(2, 1)
  ```

[image]

- If you want the items to be positioned towards the middle then just add a stretch at the beginning and end of the row so the first row should be the second:

  ```py
  self.receivebaglayout = QGridLayout(self)

  self.receivebaglayout.setRowStretch(0, 1)

  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.From, 1, 0)
  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.To, 1, 1)
  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.Type, 1, 2)
  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.Number, 1, 3)

  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.fromentry, 2, 0)
  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.toentry, 2, 1)
  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.typeentry, 2, 2)
  self.receivebaglayout.addWidget(self.numentry, 2, 3)

  self.receivebaglayout.setRowStretch(3, 1)

  self.receivebaglayout.setSpacing(10)
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. For future learning is there any page where i can know about these details based on layout designing. That could help me spend time on learning

Comment: @T2Square If you want to know how a function, class, etc. how it works then where should you look? Well, in the docs sir, for example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html, in addition there are hundreds of tutorials that cover this topic.

Comment: could you please check on this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67839737/dynamic-adding-of-checkbox-aborting-the-script-with-no-error]